# Enable Query Logging in SQLite 3

Tags: sql, database, sqlite, logging, built-in

Is there any built-in function to enable query log in SQLite.

I'm familiar with [Trace](http://www.sqlite.org/c3ref/profile.html) API, but I want to know if there is any predefined function for it.

Comment: The trace API linked to in the question is now deprecated, [v2 can be found via this link](http://www.sqlite.org/c3ref/trace_v2.html).

Answer (score 18, accepted):

There is no easy way to do this like with MySQL, but there are some options:

**One:**

Some wrapper-libraries have something like this built-in.  But to find a wrapper library you would probably first need to identify the target language.  Perl DBI? Python? C++?

**Two:**

I would **not** (in any way) recommend the following for a "production-grade" solution, but if you are mainly experimenting and/or debugging, then you might try examining the rollback journal just prior to the end of each transaction.  [See here about the rollback journal: http://www.sqlite.org/tempfiles.html](http://www.sqlite.org/tempfiles.html)  How you would detect 'the end of each transaction' would be up to your code and/or the breakpoints in your debugger.

I must emphasize again: *what I just mentioned above would be a total hack-around*, and I feel dirty even having mentioned it.

**Three:**

You could ask on the (very active and gracious) [sqlite mailing list](http://sqlite.org:8080/cgi-bin/mailman/listinfo/sqlite-users), but they would probably just reemphasize sqlite3_trace.

**... other random thing:**

On a somewhat (barely?) related note, when you start a './sqlite3' command prompt session, you can type:

```
.explain
```

which enables interesting and instructive verbose output for each query executed at the prompt.

**More Info I Just Found:**

[One of the flags that can be passed to 'sqlite3_config()' is SQLITE_CONFIG_LOG.](http://www.sqlite.org/c3ref/c_config_getmalloc.html)  This is another way (in addition to the trace API) to set a callback and receive status information from the sqlite library periodically.  I think it is mainly for error log messages.

Comment: Maybe you can start the answer of this question with "no", It might be a bit misleading here looking at the OP's question