# Getting timeout on django application

Tags: python, django, debugging

I'm currently working on a django application. I can't add an element to my database on the admin view. I fill all the information but when I click on save button but the operation doesn't finish and I get a timeout. I use sqlite3 as database.

My question is there any one that know the origin of this problem. If not how could I investigate the problem. When I worked with other language (Java, C ...etc) when I have a problem I can use a debugger. What are the options I have?

Comment: If you're used to using debuggers, why not use one in Django? Python comes with one built-in: pdb.

Comment: @DanielRoseman I'm not familiar with this debugger it is too complicated.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This Problem can occur because of **following reasons**:

1. **(Less Probable) You computation code is too Slow**: Which is a rarity because the Timeout is set to about 1 minute or so, and code doesn't take that time to Execute
2. **Your app is waiting on some external** resource but it is not Responding. For this you will have to check for the **Django logs** and check if some external resource error is there
3. **(Most Probable) Database taking too much time**: This can occur either because:

   - ***App can't connect to Database***: For this you have to check **database logs** **OR** try and **connect manually** with database through `python manage.py dbshell`
   - ***DB Query Taking so much time*** to execute: You can test this by checking **database logs** for how much time a query is taking **OR** you can connect manually via dbshell and make the same query there

Your can also use **tools** Like [django-profiler](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/django-profiler/2.0.0) , [Django debug toolbar](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/django-debug-toolbar) etc for debugging purposes. and for native python code [python debugger](https://docs.python.org/2/library/pdb.html)

Comment: thanks it was the third case. I have removed the database and it worked. You said I might check database logs but how to do that with sqlite3 database?

Comment: There are some ways to do that, See: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10910157/enable-query-logging-in-sqlite-3. But other database will provide better logs as they are more mature.